# What is the phenomenon that one can recognize a movie after seeing a scene for a fraction of second called?

Tags: perception, memory

I have experiences that while I was walking around the street, I saw a scene on a TV for a fraction of second, and I instantly recognized the correspondent movie. This is very interesting since at the time I didn't fully comprehend what I saw, but the name of movie came up anyway.

What is this very fast recollection phenomenon called? What is the type of memory involved? Where can I learn more about this cognitive function?

Comment: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/visual+association

Answer (score 3):

The subliminal recollection is called [involuntary memory retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_%28memory%29#Involuntary_memory_retrieval).

This triggers an [implicit memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_memory).

Further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli#Images
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli#Auditory_stimuli
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreading_activation